# How to know whether device has data connection?

Tags: android, connectivity

I'm trying to detect whether a device has a wifi or 3g connection. If it has a connection it will display the `MapView`, but I'm having problems with my conditional statement when neither of the two is connected.

Here's how I check for a network connection:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Here is the code where I call the method. It displays the `MapView` when it has internet access, but it does not display the toast when it has no internet access.

```
if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
    if (loc != null && !loc.equals("")) {
        new GeocoderTask().execute(loc);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Internet Connection is Required to view this map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your loop returns the correct values, let's take out the local booleans since they are unnecessary:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") && ni.isConnected())
            return true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE") && ni.isConnected())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

If the loop is incorrect, you can incorporate [the documentation's method](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) in your code:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(activeNetwork != null)
        return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check whether an internet connection is available:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    //boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    //boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                return true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong in the following:

```
if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
        if (loc != null && !loc.equals("")) {
            new GeocoderTask().execute(loc);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Internet Connection is Required to view this map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

If haveNetworkConnection () is false you'll never get to the Toast. You should change it as follows:

```
if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
            if (loc != null && !loc.equals("")) {
                new GeocoderTask().execute(loc);
            } 
        }
else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Internet Connection is Required to view this map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```